# Most efficient way to find the smallest index where its value minus the value of a previous index is smaller than a given x?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, data-structures

I have five long integers p, q, s, m and x. An array numbers[] is created by the following formula.

```
numbers[0] = s;
for(int i=1; i<numbers.Length;i++){
    numbers[i] = (p * numbers[i-1] + q) % m;
}
```

The first value of numbers (numbers[0]) is s.

What is the most efficient way to find index j where `i < j` and `|numbers[j] - numbers[i]| <= x` or `|numbers[j] - numbers[i]| >= m-x`.

For instance, in a case where p = 3, q= 7, s= 1, m= 29 en x= 1 the array will be:

numbers[0] = 1, numbers[1] = 10, numbers[2] = 8 and numbers[3] = 2.

In this case index j would be 3, because `numbers[3] - numbers[0]<=x`, because x is 1.

I thought about using something such as a variant of counting sort or radix sort but I can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i < j, then you need to grant that numbers has a length of at least 2.

You could do two nested loops, the outer one ranging from j = 1 to numbers.Length - 1 (granting the possible solution to be the smallest j) to i = 0 to i < j.

Then you compare both positions according your specs. If true, return j. If it finishes both loops, then there is no solution.

**Edit: Code Sample**

```
public int GetSmallestIndex(long[] numbers, long x, long m)
{
    if (numbers.Length >= 2)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < numbers.Length; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
            {
                long diff = Math.Abs(numbers[j] - numbers[i]); 
                if (diff <= x || diff >= m - x)
                    return j;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1; //If no solution is found, return -1 as convention
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel! Do you think this is efficient enough for long numbers?

Comment: yes large arrays and long integers with the least amount of comparisons

Comment: Also a correction in my answer: the values compared must be absolute, so numbers[j] - numbers[i] should be |numbers[j] - numbers[i]|

Comment: Long integers make no difference on computational comparison. As for the long arrays, this is a problem of worst case complexity O(n^2), as in you'll have to iterate on both arrays. So yes, I think it is quite efficient

Comment: I need something faster than n^2 though, the correction program gives me run-time exceptions.

Comment: Well but that's just the nature of the problem. In worst case (no solution), we'll always have to run through every element of the array to compare them all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78035/discussion-between-user1760791-and-gabriel-rainha).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to find out if something is more efficient is to benchmark it by using the `StopWatch` in `System.Diagnostics`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            const long x = 1;
            var numbers = new long[] {3, 7, 1, 29};
            var theSmallestIndex = SmallestIndex(x, numbers);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time: {0}", stopWatch.Elapsed);
            Console.WriteLine("Smallest Index: {0}", theSmallestIndex);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static long SmallestIndex(long x, long[] numbers)
        {
            var values = ValuesMinusTheValueOfPreviousIndex(x, numbers.ToList());
            var smallest = values.Values.OrderBy(n => n).FirstOrDefault();
            var result = values.Where(n => n.Value.Equals(smallest));
            return result.FirstOrDefault().Key;
        }

        public static Dictionary<int, long> ValuesMinusTheValueOfPreviousIndex(long x, List<long> numbers)
        {
            var results = new Dictionary<int, long>();
            foreach (var number in numbers)
            {
                var index = numbers.IndexOf(number);
                var previousNumber = index > 0 ? numbers.ElementAt(index - 1) : 0;
                var result = number - previousNumber;
                results.Add(index, result);
            }

            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Added Math.Abs as you requested in the comments

```
        long p = 3, q = 7, s = 1, m = 29, x = 1;
        long[] numbers = new long[10];

        numbers[0] = s;
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = (p * numbers[i - 1] + q) % m;
        }

        // Find the smallest index j in numbers, where i < j && 
        //    (numbers[j] - numbers[i] <= x    ||     numbers[j] - numbers[i] >= m-x)
        int smallestIndex = 0;
        long comparison;
        for (int j = 1; j < numbers.Length; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
            {
                comparison = Math.Abs(numbers[j] - numbers[i]);
                if (comparison <= x || comparison >= m - x)
                {
                    smallestIndex = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (smallestIndex != 0) break;
        }

        if (smallestIndex == 0)
        {
            // No result matches the conditions
        }
        else
        {
            // j is the smallest index matching the conditions
            // Before using Abs, in the example j is 2, because 8 - 10 = -2, lesser than x
            // Now using absolute values, In the example j is 3
        }
```

Comment: Also a correction in my answer: the values compared must be absolute, so numbers[j] - numbers[i] should be |numbers[j] - numbers[i]|